# iPhone OpenGL-ES : Stopping the light source from moving

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, lighting

I been following a [lighting guide](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-4-let.html) and set up a lighting source for my spinning cube (spins by user interaction on 3 axis)

However, whatever I do, I can't keep the light source stay in the right position, it seems to rotate with the cube.  So if I rotate the cube one part of is lit and one one part is not.

I am doing quite a bit of matrix manipulation.  I tried resetting up the matrix and then applying the light source, I tried `glLoadIdentity()` to reset the view.

I just can't seem to keep it still.

```
static const Vertex3D light0Position[] = {{0.0, 10.0, 10.0}};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (const GLfloat *)light0Position); 

// Calculate light vector so it points at the object
static const Vertex3D objectPoint[] = {{8.0, 8.0, -4.0}};
const Vertex3D lightVector = Vector3DMakeWithStartAndEndPoints(light0Position[0], objectPoint[0]);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, (GLfloat *)&lightVector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position and spotlight direction that you specify to OpenGL ES are transformed by the current modelview matrix at the time of the call to glLightfv, and are applied to a vertex after it has been transformed by the modelview matrix at the time of the call to glDrawArrays/glDrawElements. Neither takes into account the state of the projection matrix.

In order for us to understand how your transformations might be going wrong, you’ll need to show exactly when you apply your object/world/camera transformations to the modelview matrix, and where light property specification and drawing takes place relative to this.

Comment: Is there no way to reset it.  I had to do all types of crazy stuff to get the cube to rotate how I want it to, but I need a fixed light

Comment: Do you want your light source to stay fixed relative to the camera, or some coordinate in the world that your camera moves through? How are you creating/updating the modelview matrix now, and how often do you update the light properties (once per frame, or only at the start of time)?

Comment: I was trying out updating per frame.  There is no camera (e.g glLookAt).  It just a 3D cube that is rendered in front of me that rotates based on user input.  It carries on rotating by using glMultMatrixf.  I basically need it to shine on to the top front right corner of the cube whatever the rotation is.

Comment: If “top right” is defined relative to the screen, then it should be sufficient to specify your light position and direction in clip space at the start of time before you put any additional rotations in the modelview matrix. This will ensure that the lighting is always applied relative to the screen after whatever transformations to the cube have been applied.